# When building an entity model with MarkLogic Data Hub Central, why are range path indexes created with /instance instead of /header?

Tags: marklogic

I am using data hub central to create an entity model. I'm under the impression that this is supposed to create an entity model for content that will reside under the header element of the envelope. I created some indexes and the interesting thing is that when I review the path range indexes via the admin console, the are set to the instance path and not to the header path, e.g.,

`/(es:envelope|envelope)/(es:instance|instance)/someEntityModel/referenceCount`

I expected:

`/(es:envelope|envelope)/(es:header|header)/someEntityModel/referenceCount`

What's up with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entity instance data is expected to be under `/envelope/instance/(entity type name)`, and thus that's the location of the path range indexes.